# I am trying to save and load to local storage but I keep getting the error "Local storage is not defined"

Tags: javascript, html, css, function, file

I don't know what the problem is, I am trying to save variables, please help. I am trying to save and load but keep getting the error messages involving my save() function and the button calling it. Please help me with this issue, I have been trying to fix it for about 30 minutes and haven't had any luck.

```js
var money = 50;

var printpower = 0;

var autoclickprice = 50;

var autoclick = 0;

var printpowerprice = 50;

var gems = 0;

var fakegems = 0;

var gemcost = 1000;

var gemgrowercost = 5;

var gemgrower = 0;

var gemsellprice = 1250;

function update() {

  document.getElementById('TotalMoney').value = money;

  document.getElementById('MoneyPerSecond').value = autoclick;

  document.getElementById('MoneyPerClick').value = printpower;

  document.getElementById('AutoClickCost').value = autoclickprice;

  document.getElementById('PrintPowerCost').value = printpowerprice;

  document.getElementById('GemAmount').value = gems;

  document.getElementById('GemCost').value = gemcost;

  document.getElementById('GemGrowerCost').value = gemgrowercost;

  document.getElementById('GemsPerMinute').value = gemgrower;

  document.getElementById('GemSellPrice').value = gemsellprice;

  document.getElementById('FakeGemAmount').value = fakegems;

}

function add() {

  money = money + printpower;

  update();

}

function timer() {

  money = money + autoclick;

  update();

}

function buyautoclick() {

  if (money >= autoclickprice) {

    money = money - autoclickprice;

    autoclickprice = autoclickprice * 2;

    autoclick = autoclick + 1;

    update();

  }

}

function addprintpower() {

  if (money >= printpowerprice) {

    money = money - printpowerprice;


    printpowerprice = printpowerprice * 3;


    printpower = printpower + 1;


    update();

  }
}

function buygems() {

  if (money >= 1000) {

    money = money - 1000;

    gems = gems + 1;

    update();

  }

}

function buygemgrower() {

  if (gems >= gemgrowercost) {

    gems = gems - gemgrowercost;

    gemgrowercost = gemgrowercost * 2;

    gemgrower = gemgrower + 1;

    update();

  }

}

function gemsperminute() {

  fakegems = fakegems + gemgrower;

  update();

}

function sellgems() {

  if (fakegems >= 1) {

    money = money + gemsellprice;

    fakegems = fakegems - 1;

  }

}

function save() {

  localStoarge.setItem("money", "money");

}

function load() {

  const data = localStorage.getItem("money");

}

setInterval(timer, 1000);

setInterval(gemsperminute, 60000);
```

```css
#moneydiv {
  width: 225px;
  height: 925px;
  padding: 10px;
  float: left;
  background-color: lime;
}

#gemdiv {
  width: 225px;
  height: 925px;
  padding: 10px;
  float: right;
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css" />

  <title>

    Money Printer!

  </title>

</head>


<body>

  <script src="index.js">
    //nice try little kid, try agian -_-//
  </script>

  <div id="container">

    <div id="moneydiv" style="text-align: center">

      <button onclick="add()">
            
            Print Money
            
        </button>

      <button onclick="addprintpower()">
            
            Improve MPC
            
        </button>

      <br> Improve Money Per Click Cost:

      <br>

      <input type="text" id="PrintPowerCost" style disabled>

      <br> Money Per Click:

      <br>

      <input type="text" id="MoneyPerClick" style disabled>

      <br>
      <br>

      <button onclick="buyautoclick()">
            
            Buy Auto Clicker
            
        </button>

      <br> Auto Clicker Cost:

      <br>

      <input type="text" id="AutoClickCost" style disabled>

      <br> Money Per Second:

      <br>

      <input type='text' id="MoneyPerSecond" style disabled>

      <br>
      <br> Total Cash:

      <br>

      <input type="text" id="TotalMoney" style disabled>

      <br>
      <br>

    </div>

    <div id="gemdiv" style="text-align: center">

      <button onclick="buygems()">
            
            Buy Gems!
            
        </button>

      <br> Gem Cost:

      <br>

      <input type="text" id="GemCost" style disabled>

      <br>
      <br>

      <button onclick="buygemgrower()">
            
            Buy Gem Grower
            
        </button>

      <br> Gem Grower Cost(In Gems):

      <br>

      <input type="text" id="GemGrowerCost" style disabled>

      <br> Gems Per Minute:

      <br>

      <input type="text" id="GemsPerMinute" style disabled>

      <br> Total Gems:

      <br>

      <input type="text" id="GemAmount" style disabled>

      <br> Total Fake Gems:

      <br>

      <input type="text" id="FakeGemAmount" style disabled>

      <br>
      <br>

      <button onclick="sellgems()">
            
            Sell Fake Gems!
            
        </button>

      <br> Sell Price:

      <br>

      <input type="text" id="GemSellPrice" style disabled>

    </div>

    <div id="saveloaddiv" style="text-align: center;">

      <button onclick="save()">
                
                Save
                
            </button>

      <button onclick="load()">
                
                Load
                
            </button>

    </div>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: In Function Save you have a typo localStoarge instead of localStorage.

Comment: I fixed the typo and now it won't save at all, it just does not do it, how can I fix this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a typographical error, you wrote "stoarge" instead of "storage" while defining the save function

Comment: I am so dumb thank you so much

Comment: I fixed this typo, and now it just won't save, what can I do to fix this?

Comment: I guess you want it to save variable money instead of string money, then , you need to remove the quote around the second parameter of the setItem function. Like this: setItem("money", money). I also admit I may not get your question well, if it isn't this, please clarify the question so I can understand you better. Thanks

Comment: I am trying to save all of my variables into the local storage in my browser chrome, I have tried removing the quotes to save the variable, and this doesn't not seem to work either, I want to make it so that when I hit the save button, it saves all of my variables, then later when the user comes back to the page and hits load, their progress returns. I am sorry for not being more clear in this question.

Comment: okay. I checked your code again and I assume you did something wrong. I think the update function should work the other way. This is what I mean. instead of document.getElementById('TotalMoney').value = money; I think you want to do this: money = document.getElementById('TotalMoney').value;